# Invert WPF GridView to bind items to columns instead of rows

Tags: wpf, gridview, listview

Is there a simple way to invert a WPF [`GridView`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.gridview.aspx) so that items are bound to columns instead of rows? Or would it be necessary to [write a custom view mode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms748859.aspx)?

Comment: I can think of a horrendous hack that might just work...  but I don't think it's possible in any sensible way.

Comment: Would it involve rotating the grid by 90 degrees and rotating all of the cells within it? That's one horrendous possibility ^_^

Answer (score 0):

If you would like to show 3 columns with simple values, and then a last column with collection of data as itemssource, then you can put a grid within the last cell and trasform it 90 degrees.

This is the way, and also gives a performance improvement as adding and rendering columns is much slower than adding rows to a grid.